# Dropdown menu is disappearing under content

Tags: css, html

You can see the problem here: http://www.animavivo.com/

When you hover over "Styles", you should see three dropdown items. For some reason, part of it is showing and the rest is disappearing under my container div. Why?

I've done some research but I can't seem to find the answer :S thanks in advance!

Comment: By what you've shared, the only thing I can tell you is you need to use `z-index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have overflow set to hidden on your navbar:

```
#navbar {
    ...
    overflow: hidden; //remove this line
    ...
}
```

Comment: Dang it, I knew it was something simple. Thanks, Neel!

Comment: pleasure is all mine :) if you think this thing solved your problem or near by then mark it as answer so i could earn some points :P

Answer (score 0):

Set a z-index to your navigations li ul element

Answer (score 0):

Give `postion:absolute` to the `<ul>` you want to show on hover.

also add `z-index` to the perticualr item